# Count number of slots in a template in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function, that will count the number of slots in a template. Such `template ({})foo{}{} = 3`. I have function prototype as

```
template :: Template -> Int
templatey (Template xs) =
```

And some helper functions:

```
data Slot = Slot
      deriving (Show, Eq)

data Template =
    Template [Either String Slot]
    deriving Eq

instance Show Template where
 show (Template xs) =   concat $ map f xs
    where f (Left x) = x
      f (Right x) = "{}"

data Def =
    Def [Template]
    deriving Eq
```

I wrote that:

`temp = Template [Right Slot]`
And I guess I need to use map somehow to check if input template matches temp. But, I can't find the way how to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with the `TemplateHaskell` language extension, or just something you're calling a template?

Comment: @dfeuer hmm well I guess it's just something we call template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
template :: Template -> Int
template (Template xs) = sum $ map (\x -> either (\_ -> 0) (\_ -> 1) x) xs
```

In case you are seeing value of `Right` value constructor, you are returning `1` else `0`. And finally you just sum it up to get the number of slots.

Or as Yuuri points out, this is more elegant:

```
template :: Template -> Int
template (Template xs) = sum $ map (either (const 0) (const 1)) xs
```

Or even this:

```
import Data.Either (rights)

template :: Template -> Int
template (Template xs) = length $ rights xs
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> template $ Template [Right Slot, Right Slot, Right Slot]
3
λ> template $ Template [Right Slot, Right Slot, Right Slot, Left "hi"]
3
λ> template $ Template [Right Slot, Right Slot, Right Slot, Left "hi", Right Slot]
4
λ> template $ Template []
0
```

Comment: I'd consider using `map (either (const 0) (const 1))` in the first example.

Comment: @Yuuri, That's cleaner. Updated the answer.